Can two liquids affect each other in Blender?
There are two liquids: one has high viscosity and doesn't flow well, and the other is water, so I want the water to push the high-viscosity liquid. Is it possible to implement this? If so, could you give me some advice? Is it possible to do this without using plugins like Flip Fluids?

I don't think you can. Viscosity is a domain property and 2 domains can't interact with each other.

No, just as @Lutzi said, this is not possible with Blender's Mantaflow. Or to be more precise, since the title of your question only says "two liquids affect each other": you can have two liquid sources i.e. flow objects affect each other, but they will both be the same. So, since the viscosity and overall material is set by the domain, you cannot have two different liquids affect each other. They cannot have different settings, not even different colors (even though in smoke simulations you can have different smoke colors for different smoke emitters within the same domain).
